# spring-data-neo4j: Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: More than one class has simple name

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I have two classes annotated with `@NodeEntity` with same name `Board` in different packages. The labels `@NodeEntity(label='')` of them are different and I've got error above when execute query. Why I can't do that?

Comment: Could it be because it tries to use class name as seed for naming a database table?

Comment: The 'labels' exist to replace the default entity names in db. @NodeEntity(label='...')

Comment: I use spring-data-neo4j 4.2